# Pass array as argument

Tags: c++, arrays, argument-passing

I have an array:

```
int *BC_type_vel;
BC_type_vel = new int [nBou+1];
```

and a function:

```
void BC_update (const int type[], float X[]) {

for (int i=1; i<=nBou; ++i) {

    if (type[i] == 1) {

        std::cout << i << "   " << type[i] << "   " << BC_type_vel[i] << std:: endl;

        for (int e=PSiS[i]; e<PSiE[i]; ++e) {               

            X[e] = X[elm[e].neigh[0]];
        }
    }
}
```

}

I call it as:

```
BC_update(BC_type_vel,U);
```

It gives output as:

```
1   1   0
2   1   0
3   1   0
4   1   1
5   1   0
```

So why the function argument does not copy values properly?

Comment: Beware that array in C starts at the position 0 (basemen + 0). You are  getting into bogus memory at your function.

Comment: @Edu: It's a very odd way to loop through an array and should be changed, but he isn't actually overruning it.  If you look at how the array is created it has `nBou+1` elements and it loops through 1 to `nBou`.  Now he doesn't show us how he is populating the array, so I would guess that is the problem.  I would recommend tagging this as C though as in C++ you should just use a `vector` and make your life easier.

Comment: @EdS. It is true. He is just wasting the first row but no damage to the memory. I agree, this is just C, not C++

Comment: @Shibli: Please tell us why you think the output is improper.  What is in `BC_type_vel`?  What output were you expecting?

Comment: Inside the function, type and BC_type_vel point to the same memory position. Why do they print different values?

Comment: I read `BC_type_vel` from a text file without any problem. Here the problem is with passing array to function but cannot find the reason. It is expected that `BC_type_vel` should be equal to `type`. So the second column should be equal to third one.

Comment: *"I read BC_type_vel from a text file without any problem"* - Are you sure about that?  What happens if you skip reading the text file and just give the function a set of known inputs, i.e., create the array manually?

Comment: I read and verify that `BC_type_vel` was read correctly. Even this does not matter. My question is why `type`and `BC_type_vel` are not equal if I copy content of `BC_type_vel` to `type` by passing argument?

Comment: @Shibli: Please show more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried following code with gcc:

```
int *BC_type_vel;
int nBou = 10;

void BC_update (const int type[]) {
    for (int i=1; i<=nBou; ++i) {
        if (type[i] == 1)
            std::cout << i << "   " << type[i] << "   " << BC_type_vel[i] << std:: endl;
    }
}

int main () {
    int i;

    BC_type_vel = new int [nBou+1];
    for (i=1; i<=nBou; ++i) {
        if (i%2 == 0)
            BC_type_vel[i] = i;
        else
            BC_type_vel[i] = 1;
    }
    BC_update(BC_type_vel);

    return 0;
}
```

and it gives the expected results:

```
1   1   1
3   1   1
5   1   1
7   1   1
9   1   1
```

So the problem is somewhere else in your code. You need to provide us with the rest of it.